# Updating from Asp.Net Identity 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, nuget-package, solution-explorer

I can't seem to update my AspNet.Identity.Core, AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and AspNet.Identity.Owin references in Solution Explorer to 2.0.

I used Nuget to try and update these packages, but it can't seem to find them.  I uninstalled the identity packages using Nuget and reinstalled them, but the references in Solution Explorer are still to version 1.0, and I can't perform any updates.

Has anyone had this problem before?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually deleting the Identity .dll files in your solution and reinstalling the packages? You can also run the install command from the Package Manager Console. (e.g. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin)

Comment: Thanks, if I were to delete the dll files from the project bin folder and reinstall Identity I get errors like 'Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version-2.0.0.0, Culture-neutral ... which has a higher version than referenced assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version-2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral ...'.

Comment: You might wanna try deleting them from your packages folder too. Remember to delete all 3 of them and re install thereafter.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this didn't seem to work either.  I uninstalled the packages, removed the dlls, then reinstalled them, all with Nuget.  I get the same errors.  At this stage, it's easier for me to copy the project files over to a new project.